# Solution to create Automatic Tests both for Web Application and Desktop Outlook application

Tags: selenium, outlook, automated-tests, ui-automation

My problem is following:

I'm testing Web application in selenium. One of the application features is sending some PDF files. After the click action on certain button, web application opens desktop Outlook application and opens window with new message, where mentioned pdf file is added as attachment. I need to assert if the file is actually added. Obviously it's not possible with only selenium to interact with desktop Outlook application.

So my question is, is it even possible to write one test which would interact both with Web Application in first steps and in next steps with Outlook? Can you recommend me some technological stack which would let me achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to simply combine browser and desktop automation. There are variety of approaches

1. [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/) - commercial tool that can work with both web and desktop UI
2. Vanilla Selenium + [Windows driver by Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) wrapped with your favorite language
3. java.awt.Robot as an alternative for desktop app interaction

Comment: that was exactly what I needed, I decided to use Seleium + Appium :)

Answer (score 0):

try this library, support both desktop and web automation and supply unified python api:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium
the sample shows for both web and desktop automation cases:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator, ui

def main():
    # sample code to demo web automation and desktop application
    tab = cc.edge.open("https://www.bing.com/")
    tab.find_element(
        locator.new_store.sample.bing.search_sb_form_q).set_text('clicknium')
    tab.find_element(locator.new_store.sample.bing.svg).click()
    sleep(3)
    tab.close()

    process = subprocess.Popen("notepad")
    ui(locator.new_store.sample.notepad.document_15).set_text("clicknium")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```